# Ruby on rails with Bootstrap modals - Make a button to reload modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and Bootstrap modals.

I have a link to a controller action on my site that opens in a modal.  I am doing this using ajax to put a helper file into a div.  The controller action grabs a random product from a model.  I would like a button in my modal to 'reload' the modal.  In other words close the modal and re-open it calling the controller action again so we have a new product.

I would also like to know how I can make a button in the modal that is linked to a different controller action(which changes an attribute in the database), and then reloads the modal.

**example_controller.rb**

```
def onsale
    @item= Products.(code to get random product)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**_header.html.erb**  Here I am showing the link that opens the modal.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><%= link_to "Sale Items", onsale_path,  :remote => true %></li>
          </ul>
        <% end %>
</div>
```

I put this code  `<div id="onsale-modal"></div>` some random place in the body of application.html.erb

**onsale.js.erb**

```
$("#onsale-modal").html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'onsale') %>');
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

**_onsale.html.erb**

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= image_tag @item.picture.large.url %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="reload">Reload</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

I added this code

```
$('#reload').on('click', function () {
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  $.ajax("/onsale");
});
```

to onsale.js.erb and it seems to be working.  Is there anything wrong doing it this way?